# Pl/SQL function not return all the fields

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have below function which is working fine. The only problem is its only returning the value OF `V_KPI_NAME` from the `BODY`. As you can see i am also passing `IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP`,`V_KPI_TPE` but its not returning those values.

```
FUNCTION BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY
(
  IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP
, IN_ALERT_LOGS_LOG_DESC IN VARCHAR2
, IN_KPI_LOG_ID IN NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BODY VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
V_KPI_DEF_ID NUMBER;
V_KPI_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
V_KPI_DESC VARCHAR2(500);
V_KPI_TYPE VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
-- ,'yyyy-MM-dd H24 mm ss'
Select KPI_DEF_ID INTO V_KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_LOGS WHERE KPI_LOG_ID = IN_KPI_LOG_ID;


Select NAME INTO V_KPI_TYPE FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_TYPE KT ON KD.KPI_TYPE = KT.KPI_TYPE_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;
Select KPI_NAME INTO V_KPI_NAME FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;
Select KPI_DESC INTO V_KPI_DESC FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

  BODY := to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') || Chr(13);
  BODY := V_KPI_NAME || Chr(13) ;
  BODY := V_KPI_TYPE || Chr(13) ;

  RETURN BODY;
END BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BODY := to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') || Chr(13);
BODY := V_KPI_NAME || Chr(13) ;
BODY := V_KPI_TYPE || Chr(13) ;
```

Each one your are overwriting the object.

```
BODY := to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') || Chr(13);
BODY := BODY || V_KPI_NAME || Chr(13) ;
BODY := BODY || V_KPI_TYPE || Chr(13) ;
```

Comment: Ohh its working and i want to include semicolon between each and every body value because right now i am getting comdined body values, there are no spaces.

Comment: Well, i'm sure you can concatenate the appropriate values where you require them!